# Should I refer to controller.model or controller.content in a view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

If I have a model of products and in my view I loop over them both of the below is valid.

Which one should I use? 
Is there a reason for both?

I prefer `controller.model`, seems more explicit.

```
{{#each product in controller.model}}
    <div>{{product.artist}}</div>
{{/each}}


{{#each product in controller.content}}
    <div>{{product.artist}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which one should I use?

Actually neither. Instead you should bind to the controller itself, like this:

```
{{#each product in controller}}
  <div>{{product.artist}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

While `controller.content` and `controller.model` appear to work at first, you'll find that this approach breaks for more advanced use cases like sorting and specifying an itemController.

> Is there a reason for both?

AFAIK there is no difference between using `controller.content` and `controller.model`. The model property is really an alias to the content property.

```
// Ember controller definition:
model: Em.computed.alias('content')
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be even to just use: {{#each product}} ?

Comment: That wouldn't work, the product parameter is just telling `{{each}}` helper how to name each item. But you could say `{{each controller}}` and then reference attributes like `{{artist}}` within the code block.    See this jsfiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/gL9eB/

Answer (score 0):

From ember source code seems that the `model` is an alias for `content`:

```
Ember.ControllerMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    ...
    model: Ember.computed.alias('content'),
    ...
});
```